# "Dividing" an integer into pieces (different tax for certain thresholds of income - C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, function, integer

Hi guys and thanks in advance

I'm struggling with a c++ program which should calculate the tax for a given income based on different tax for certain thresholds, like:
0% for first 10.000$
5% for another 10.000$
and 15% for the rest of $

Everything I've managed to write is this invalid (result is always -0.3) code:

```
double tax_calculator(double income) {
    double result = 0;
    // threshold is array for tax thresholds, e.g 10000 or 20000$
    int tokens[4];
    for (int i = 1, y = 0; i <= income; i++) {
        if (i > treshold[y]) {
            // assign i to temporary var
            tokens[y] = i;
            i = 1;
            y++;
        }
    }
    for (int z = 0; z < 4; z++)
        // tax is array of base tax values, like 5, 10 and 15 (%).
        result += tokens[z] * tax[z] / 100.0;
    return result;
}
```

Hope you give me some advice :)

Comment: You're pulling in a bunch of global variables, which makes your code hard to maintain and usually leads to trouble...

Comment: The method you are using is very inefficient and has bugs, I would rewrite this piece completely. But if you still want help finding out what is wrong with this specific snippet, please provide the values of threshold and income that you tested it with.

Comment: What is stopping `y` in your loop from going into uncharted territory?  At the very least, you should ensure that `tokens[y]` is a valid entry.

Comment: what organization are you writing it for? Why isn't anybody warning [against using floating point numbers for currency?](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/08/14/currency-rounding-errors/)

Answer (score 1):

The key is that taxes are based on *brackets*, not individual values. You should think about them like a table:

```
min      |   max     |  pct
$0       |  $10,000  |   0%
$10,000  |  $20,000  |   5%
$20,000  |   +inf    |  15%
```

So if we define a bracket like:

```
struct bracket {
    double min;
    double pct;
};
```

We can use the *next* bracket's `min` to the the max. So in your case:

```
std::vector<bracket> brackets = { {0, 0.0}, {10000, 0.05}, {20000, 0.15} };

double income = ???;
double taxes = 0.0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < brackets.size(); ++i) {
    double cur = (i == brackets.size() - 1) ? income : std::min(income, brackets[i+1].min);
    cur = std::max(0.0, cur - brackets[i].min);
    taxes += cur * brakcets[i].pct;
}
```

For an income of, say, $100000, the first line would set `cur` to be `{10000, 20000, 100000}`. The second line would reduce it to `{10000, 10000, 80000}`. And the last line would give you the taxes as `{0.0, 500, 12000}`... leading to a final result of $12,500.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by myself already, but I want to know your opinion about it. Thanks.

```
double tax_calculator(double income) {
    // temporary var to hold tokened-income
    int var[Thresholds_amount] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < Thresholds_amount; i++) {
        // if income after subtraction is greater or equal to zero
        if (income - Threshold_level[i] >= 0) {
            // assign the entire threshold level to proper var
            var[i] = Threshold_level[i];
            // subtract the threshold level from income for real
            income -= Threshold_level[i];
        }
        else {
            // assign the rest of the value to proper var
            var[i] = income;
            // exit the loop
            break;
        }
    }
    double result = 0.0;
    // consolidate all taxes
    for (int y = 0; y < Thresholds_amount; y++)
        result += var[y] * Base_tax[y] / 100.0;
    return result;
}
```

Values for some variables that were created outside of the function:

```
const short Thresholds_amount = 4;
const int Threshold_level[Thresholds_amount] = { 5000, 10000, 20000, 35000 };
const int Base_tax[Thresholds_amount] = { 0, 10, 15, 20 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I took some cues from the answer by @Barry and made some changes with the hope that it is an improvement over his answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cfloat>
#include <algorithm>

struct bracket
{
   // Use max in the bracket instead of min.
   double max;
   double pct;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   std::vector<bracket> brackets = { {10000.0, 0.0}, {20000, 0.05}, {DBL_MAX, 0.15} };

   double income = atof(argv[1]);
   double taxes = 0.0;

   // There are no taxes if the income is less than 10000.0.
   // There is no need to check for that bracket.
   for (size_t i = 1; i < brackets.size(); ++i)
   {
      double cur = std::min(income, brackets[i].max);
      taxes += (cur - brackets[i-1].max) * brackets[i].pct;

      // If income is less than or equal to the current bracket's max,
      // there is no need to compute any more tax amounts.
      if ( income <= brackets[i].max )
      {
         break;
      }
   }

   std::cout << "Income: " << income << ", tax amount: " << taxes << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```